# jquery ui tabs stay on tab after form submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, tabs

Hi I'm using jQuery ui tabs Widget in a page with two tabs. Each page contains one form with the same page as an action.
I need to stay in the tab where the form was submitted after the form is submitted.
How can I accomplish that?.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>I'm Tab1.</p>
       <p>I'm a Form using GET Method, passing values to this same page:<br></p>
       <p><form name="input" action="index.php" method="GET">
       <input type="text" name="value" id="somevalue" style="width:150px;"> <br>
       </form></p>
    <?
    if (isset($_GET)) {echo ($_GET['value']);}
    ?>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>I'm Tab2.</p>
     <p>I'm a Form using GET Method, passing values to this same page:<br></p>
       <p><form name="input" action="index.php" method="GET">
       <input type="text" name="value2" id="somevalue" style="width:150px;"> <br>
       </form></p>
    <?
       if (isset($_GET)) {echo ($_GET['value2']);}
    ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

You need to save selected tab index to cookies and on each load of page read those cookie and select appropriate tab.
Saving is made inside [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) handler of tabs plugin (value of the [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option will be saved)

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui){
        var active = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
        $.cookie("activeTabIndex", active);
    }
});
```

To select needed tab at page load you need to read the cookie and set the `active` option on tabs.
Here is the full `$(document).ready` code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initialize tabs plugin with listening on activate event
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui){
            //get the active tab index
            var active = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");

            //save it to cookies
            $.cookie("activeTabIndex", active);
        }
    });

    //read the cookie
    var activeTabIndex = $.cookie("activeTabIndex");

    //make active needed tab
    if(activeTabIndex !== undefined) {
        tabs.tabs("option", "active", activeTabIndex);
    }
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/V9k7H/)

(i removed the `form`s to make it work in jSFiddle; if you are staying on the same page after submitting your `form`, it will work)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very explanatory answer

Comment: For developers like me that still use an old version of jQuery: use 'select' instead of activate, use 'ui.index' to retrieve the selected index and use tabs.tabs("select", activeTabIndex) to select the proper tab.